# UIPopOverController Arrow direction in tableview | iPad

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I want to show a `UIPopover` controller in a `UITableView`. I want to show it either above or below the selected row. But currently it is covering the selected Row. Any help ?